# traceur compiler runtime vs build

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As the ES6 spec is nearing completion, I'm investigating get a jump start on ES6 syntax and leveraging [traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) compiler to do so.

My question is that I see that tracuer requires a 'runtime' file to be included on the page, is this a shim for some lacking 'core' features like Array/etc OR is this a runtime converter and then the build is just for deploying?

If its just a 'shim' per say, how do you deal with always compiling during development?  I know you could do a watch in grunt but for large applications that seems very slow.  I also saw you could use a node compiler, but node is not my backend/server tech ( I use IIS, ya i know ).

Thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: It's not a converter, no. It does shim the "missing" functions, but it also does more than that and provides helper functions that are used by some features - a "runtime" if you want.

Comment: @Bergi - makes sense, but if I write ES6 classes for example and include the runtime will it automatically work or is a build step still needed?

Comment: No, the runtime is not a converter that compiles ES6 on the fly. The `class` syntax will give you a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi thats what I thought.  How are people integrating this converter and being efficient while developing then?  Maybe run all my .js assets in IIS through a node pipeline?